# How to calculate mean and sample vector containing strings

Tags: r

I need to calculate the mean of this `jar` variable that contains both red and blue marbles. so I created two objects red and blue, 50 each, created a vector and inserted it into a object called Jar. So my jar contains 50 blue and 50 red.

I have to sample 10 marbles, determine how many are red and then calculate the percentage. For the sample, I used the following code:

```r
sample(length(jar), 10, replace = TRUE)
 [1] 43 48 77 98 34 21 29 64 95 54
```

I am not sure if I am using the right code. And second, how does it show which one is red and which one is blue? Sorry I am new to R and stats. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: we're not here to do your homework for you, show us what you have tried and we will help.  please read this and try to ask again https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: look into `table`

Comment: Can you post you code for your jar vector?